# SQL Query to show highest sales in a City for EACH State

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT c.STATE, c.CITY, SUM(s.QTY * s.SALEPRICE)
FROM DWSALE s
INNER JOIN DWCUST c
ON s.dwcustid = c.dwcustid
GROUP BY c.STATE, c.CITY
ORDER BY c.STATE;
```

This current query above shows the TOTAL (SUM) amount of sales made (sale = qty * saleprice) for each city while also showing the state it resides in.

Clients (found in DWCUST) live in Cities and States.
Sales are recorded in DWSALE and hold the sales info.

I need the query to show the cities with the HIGHEST sales for EACH of their respective states.
I am not sure what to do.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()` to get what you want:

```
SELECT state, city, total
FROM (SELECT c.STATE, c.CITY, SUM(s.QTY * s.SALEPRICE) as total,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.STATE ORDER BY SUM(s.QTY * s.SALEPRICE)) as seqnum
      FROM DWSALE s INNER JOIN 
           DWCUST c
           ON s.dwcustid = c.dwcustid
      GROUP BY c.STATE, c.CITY
     ) sc
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY STATE;
```

If you want ties (multiple rows for the same state), then use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
with statecitytotal as
(SELECT c.STATE, c.CITY, SUM(s.QTY * s.SALEPRICE) total
FROM DWSALE s
INNER JOIN DWCUST c
ON s.dwcustid = c.dwcustid
GROUP BY c.STATE, c.CITY
ORDER BY c.STATE)
select * from (select state, city, total, rank() over(partition by state order by total desc) rnk from statecitytotal) where rnk=1
```

but, if total for 2 cities is the same then both are shown

Comment: Works well, but the rnk thing is there, I'd rather it not be there. Voting you up though :)